# Can I change the properties of a TextBox in a separate class?

Tags: c#, winforms

Basically I want to write a method in a class that I can repeat multiple times in different forms that changes the password char property of a text box this is what I have so far

```
public class Methods
{
  public bool ShowPass;
  public char Passbox;

  public Methods (bool ShowPassVar, char PassboxChar)
  {
    Passbox = PassboxChar;
    ShowPass = ShowPassVar;
  }

  //Method to reveal and hide the password being entered
  public void ShowHidePass(bool ShowPass, char Passbox)
  {
    if (ShowPass == false)
    {
      Passbox = '\0';
      ShowPass = true;
    }
    else if (ShowPass == true)
    {
      Passbox = '*';
      ShowPass = false;
    }
  }
```

Start of form and all variables are set

```
public partial class SignUp : Form
{
  private void ShowHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //runs method to change the PasswordChar
      Methods SHP = new Methods(ShowPass, PassBox.PasswordChar);
      SHP.ShowHidePass(ShowPass, PassBox.PasswordChar);
    }
  }
```

Comment: ShowPass and Passbox shouldn't be public, since they are fields.  You already passed the information to create the class, why pass them again in your ShowHidePass method?  Your two properties are better off as [Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2019) and just get the information from there.

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A**

One way to do that is by utilizing the [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to *extend* the `TextBox` controls in your project to provide new functionalities. For example, create a new static class within your project's namespace as follow:

```cs
public static class MyTextBoxExtension
{
    //To set or clear the password char.
    public static void PasswordCharEnabled(this TextBox textBox, bool enabled, char passChar = '*')
    {
        textBox.PasswordChar = enabled ? passChar : '\0';
    }

    //Just to toggle..
    public static void PasswordCharToggle(this TextBox textBox)
    {
        textBox.PasswordChar = textBox.PasswordChar == '\0' ? '*' : '\0';
    }
}
```

and in the `ShowHide_Click` event:

```cs
private void ShowHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //to clear the PasswordChar property:
    PassBox.PasswordCharEnabled(false);

    //to set the default asterisk char:
    PassBox.PasswordCharEnabled(true);

    //to set a specific char:
    PassBox.PasswordCharEnabled(true, '^');

    //to set or clear according to the value of a Boolean variable:
    PassBox.PasswordCharEnabled(ShowPass);

    //A bool variable and a char of your choice:
    PassBox.PasswordCharEnabled(ShowPass, '+');

    //or just to toggle...
    PassBox.PasswordCharToggle();

    //Another way to toggle the bool variable first
    //then use its new value to toggle the PasswordChar property.
    PassBox.PasswordCharEnabled(ShowPass = !ShowPass);
}
```

**Plan B**

*Inheritance* way, derive a new class from the `TextBox` control and add the new methods:

```cs
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    public TextBoxEx() : base() { }

    //Hide the PasswordChar property and make it read-only
    //since the PasswordCharEnabled method is the setter.
    [Browsable(false)]
    public new char PasswordChar => base.PasswordChar;

    public void PasswordCharEnabled(bool enabled, char passChar = '*')
    {
        base.PasswordChar = enabled ? passChar : '\0';
    }

    public void  PasswordCharToggle()
    {
        base.PasswordChar = base.PasswordChar == '\0' ? '*' : '\0';
    }
}
```

**Plan C**

What's wrong with just:

```cs
private void ShowHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PassBox.PasswordChar = (ShowPass = !ShowPass) == true ? '*' : '\0';

}
```

The simplest way to toggle the `bool` variable and use its new value to toggle the `PasswordChar` property.

It's your call